# Is it possible to start processing CSV value in the next loop iteration only if it's previous run is already finished?

Tags: jmeter

I have a CSV file that contains some identifiers. I need to run a load test for each of them several times. Is there anything I can do to stop the value from being processed before it's previous run is finished?

So let's say I have 3 identifiers:

```
1
2
3
```

For 1 it takes 60 seconds to finish the process, for 2 and 3- 10 seconds. After 2 and 3 are executed next loop starts with id 1, but it's still in progress for the first iteration.

I know I can wait for all of them to finish executing before starting next loop, but after 2 and 3 are finished I need to start processing them again immediately, without waiting for 1, so for 3 iterations in order 1-2-3-2-3-2-3-1-1.

Answer (score 1):

Not with the CSV Data Set Config, you can either consider using [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) or [Redis Data Set](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-redis).

The idea is to remove the "identifier" while its being processed so other threads (virtual user) won't read it until the processing is done.

Alternatively just use separate [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to run different "identifiers"